# I have a problem with running minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I run it, I cannot play in a window, but it just works in fullscreen.

When I am on the "Mojang" loading screen, it's automatically turned into fullscreen. While in-game, I can switch it back, but if I try to play it in windowed mode, I can see anything, I can hear the music, and everything else but it's just blank, sometimes black, or even transparent. I tried every solution in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284510/minecraft-full-screen-problem#:%7E:text=Right%20click%20and%20go%20to,do%20to%20fix%20my%20issue.) but it's not working.

Comment: @Topcode With all due respect, I think you could have been able to figure out my error without my help. I mean, it's obvious once you see what the fix was. Next time, if you see an error like that, please consider suggesting an edit!

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 did you really need to make another comment for that instead of editing it?

Comment: @Topcode Yes, because I feel like you could have suggested another edit instead of making a comment in the first place. So I'm letting you know what to do in the future in this type of situation.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 i cant make 1 letter edits.... it seems you can

Comment: @Topcode Then if you're in this type of situation again later, try fixing other things in addition to changing the obvious errors. For example, see my latest edit as of just now: I've decided to fix some of the little things there as well, and that's certainly a 6-letter edit!

Comment: LOL, You corrected my question, like 3 times. And still no solution. XD (btw im not english speaking, so thers so many errors lol)

Comment: Are you using Optifine? If so, have you checked to see if you have forced fullscreen mode (which may be causing the problem) in the Optifine settings?